# How to easily "deploy" a regex-based text transformation to output a URL string?

Tags: regex, chess

I frequently apply a series of three regex-based text substitutions to an input string to generate a URL.

The input strings differ each time; the three substitutions do not vary and can be hard-coded. (For my fellow chess nerds, I'm trying to speed up the multi-step process, within Chessable, of "finding this position in a course" given its FEN.)

I know the text substitutions, e.g. I can easily do this as three steps within vim.

My question: how can I most easily "deploy" my text transformation as a one-click "app" that accepts an input string and outputs the URL I want?

Googling "online regex" returns several sites that don't quite do what I need.

Comment: I didn't understand your question, Can you add some inputs and expected output in your question?

Comment: If you need to deploy your "app" in a simple manner, you could write it in JS and deploy it to a static website provider like Github Pages or any other. https://pages.github.com/

Comment: @MihailFeraru Thanks, I used Github Pages just as you suggested!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.